# Binding to a property in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol in which i want to expose a property called ExpressionText and in the 
xaml a binding can be defined to this property.
So i created a dependency property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorText =DependencyProperty.Register("EditorText", typeof(string), typeof(MyUerControl));
```

and

```
public string ExpressionText 
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(EditorText);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(EditorText, value);
    }
}
```

in the xaml i do this.

```
     <controls:MyUerControl x:Name="textEditor" ExpressionText="{Binding 
                                  Path=Expression,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

but i get

A binding cannot be set on ExpressionText property of type MyUserControl. Binding can be set 
only on a depenedecy property of type Dependency object error.

Is there something wrong in my approach ? How do i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static DependencyProperty EditorTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ExpressionText", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl),
          new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
          { })));
public string ExpressionText
{
    get
    {
        return (string)base.GetValue(EditorTextProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(EditorTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Must say i'm surprised that my answer is accepted :P  Geoff explains what you did wrong, i'm only showing how to fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

You are defining EditorText as the name of your DependencyProperty. That is the name that is available publicly for you to bind to.  If you want it to be called ExpressionText, then you need to register that as the name.

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorText =
                           DependencyProperty.Register("ExpressionText", typeof(string), typeof(MyUerControl));
```